# CSS typing text animation repeat

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a simple CSS code that types a text.
but it only iterate one time and I want it to iterate infinite times .
I already added  `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` but it's not working. An other problem is slows down at the end . how can I change that.
here is my code :

```css
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}

.animation::before
.container{
  display: inline-block;
}
.typed-out{
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: .15em solid #990000;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation: 
    typing 5s forwards;
    width: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

    <title>Demo - Bootstrap 5 multilevel dropdown submenu sample</title>

    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/test.css" />
    <script src="./js/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
  <body>
    <style>
   
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <div>
  <h2 class="typed-out">This is a Typing Text</h2>
  </div>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: when posting a [repro]  pay extra attention to the word **minimal**! Please also note, that your HTML Markup is invalid: `</head><body><style></style></head><body>`

Answer (score 1):

you use `animation` after the `animation-iteration-count` which is a syntax that includes the iteration count. As such you overwrite it with the default value: `1`. Simply add the `infinite` to the `animation`syntax.

```css
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}

.animation::before
.container{
  display: inline-block;
}
.typed-out{
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: .15em solid #990000;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: typing 5s forwards infinite;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="typed-out">This is a Typing Text</h2>
```

Comment: tnx that worked, do you have any ideas for slowing down at the end?

Comment: You could try by adding `ease-out` but animation speed change fine-tuning is not as easy.